# How to make robocopy delete excluded files in destination directory

Tags: windows, command-line, robocopy

I have a cross-platform build toolchain which copies some folders to destination. I use `robocopy` on Windows and `rsync` on macOS because they support console progress output. The commands were in this form:

```
robocopy "C:\Some\Source" "C:\Some\Destination" /MIR
rsync -a --progress --delete "/Some/Source/" "/Some/Destination"
```

But now I am met with a situation where I need to exclude some files that may appear in the source directory. And I need them to be erased in the destination if they were there before. `rsync` has `--delete-excluded` option:

```
rsync -a --progress --delete-excluded --exclude '*.jpg' "/Some/Source/" "/Some/Destination"
```

But I can't make `robocopy` act like this using the `/XF` option:

```
robocopy "C:\Some\Source" "C:\Some\Destination" /MIR /XF *.jpg
```

`robocopy` keeps old excluded files at the destination. Is there a way to make `robocopy` behave like `rsync` with the `--delete-excluded` option? I know I can scan the destination tree later to remove excluded files with another command but I would like to do it with `robocopy` because the tree is really huge and I want to save time with the copy operation.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am having a similar problem.

Comment: @daka sorry, but I had no luck with that :( Instead I cleaned everything manually and reorganized my build pipeline so such files are not appearing anymore.